# how to prevent ggplotly from combining two factors using different aesthetics into the same legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I would expect that two different factors (z and w) using two different aesthetics (fill and shape) would get separate legends, one for fill and one for shape. How can we separate one legend into two? And how can we get rid of the (x,1) format in the legend and make it just show x? Thanks in advance for any help.

Please see this reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(stats)

ids <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

df1 <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  w = rpois(5,100),
  y = rpois(5, 100) # 5 random poisson distributed values with mean 100
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  z = rpois(5, 100),
  y = rpois(5, 100) # 5 random poisson distributed values with mean 100
)

plot <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = id)) + 
  geom_bar(data = df2, mapping = aes(y = y), stat = "identity", width=0.5, alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_point(data = df2, mapping = aes(y = y, fill = factor(z)), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data = df1, mapping = aes(y = y, shape = factor(w)), color = "green", size=5)

ggplotly(plot)
```

[image: legend combining fill and shape]

Comment: That's apparently an issue of ggplotly (or plotly, as of April 2020 at least). See suggestions here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1164#issuecomment-607894948

Comment: Thanks @I_O, I used ggplotly(plot) %>% style(showlegend = FALSE, traces = 1:numberOfUniqueValuesOfZ) based on the suggestion in https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/572